# Android TTS speaks 0 as "oh"

Tags: android

When using Android TextToSpeech to speak messages that have digits, Android is speaking 0 (zero) as "oh" rather than "zero".  All other digits are spoken as expected.

I've tried a couple different ways to speak, all of them result in this issue. First, I tried in the normal way:

```
    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(mContext, this);
    String text= "this is a test";
    String digits=  "0 0 0 1";
    String finalString= text+digits;

    // speak something using google TTS
    Bundle lParams = new Bundle();
    lParams.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, Constants.TTS_AUDIO_STREAM);
    mTTS.speak(finalString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, lParams, "");
```

I also tried `digits` as "0001" (no spaces). Both ended up spoken as "this is a test oh oh oh one".  Next, I tried using TtsSpans:

```
    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(mContext, this);
    String text= "this is a test";
    String digits=  "0 0 0 1";
    String finalString= text+digits;
    Spannable lSpannedMsg = new SpannableString( finalString );
    TtsSpan lSpan = new TtsSpan.DigitsBuilder(digits).build();
    TtsSpan lSpanText = new TtsSpan.TextBuilder(text).build();

    lSpannedMsg.setSpan(lSpan, finalString.indexOf(digits), finalString.indexOf(digits) + digits.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    lSpannedMsg.setSpan(lSpanText, finalString.indexOf(text), finalString.indexOf(text) + text.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // speak something using google TTS
    Bundle lParams = new Bundle();
    lParams.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, Constants.TTS_AUDIO_STREAM);
    mTTS.speak(lSpannedMsg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, lParams, "");
```

Even with the spanned string, the engine still spoke "this is a test oh oh oh one". Is there any way to force Google to speak 0 as "zero"?  I would like to avoid investigating the string sent in and replacing 0 with "zero" as this would cause issues with other languages.

Comment: "O" is the american way to pronouce "zero". Do you have a way to set the locale? If so, Locale.UK (en_GB) would probably make zero to be pronounced properly as the default local would be Locale.US (en_US).

Comment: I do have control over the locale, but I fear I would run into other pronunciation issues by using the UK locale for the US on other words.

Comment: Ah, well, yeah, the app might end up with a somewhat british accent :) But it won't say lift instead of elevator. If that's an issue and if an american accent is expected, is "O" an issue? Otherwise, there might be other countries, that have an accent closer to the US accent, and that use "zero" instead of "O". It could be interesting to dig into this.

Comment: "O" is only a potential confusion point. This application also utilizes speech recognition, and when speaking to the device a user must speak numbers as "zero zero one" to be properly recognized. So, we hope to have the application speak to the user in the same fashion as it expects to be spoken to.

Comment: Try: `String digits=  "zero zero zero one";`

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.mEmployeeId.setText("100001");
String buildNumber = holder.mEmployeeId.getText().toString();
StringBuilder builderForEmployeeNo = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : buildNumber.toCharArray()){
    builderForEmployeeNo.append(ch);
    builderForEmployeeNo.append(",");
}
holder.mEmployeeId.setContentDescription(builderForEmployeeNo);
```

By using this method no matter your default locale it will read 0 as zero only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).